# How is Korean language proficiency evaluated for the F-2 (resident) visa?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, language, south-korea, language-test

The F-2 is a resident visa. With such a visa, one can stay up to 3 years in Korea and can work and have a business and after 3 years, is eligible for a F-5 visa (permanent resident).

Eligibility to F-2 visa is determined through a point system taking account age, education, income and Korean proficiency.

**How is Korean proficiency** assessed for the F-2 visa?

This [website](https://www.korea4expats.com/article-point-system-to-obtain-F2-visa.html) explains that it is determined by the S-TOPIK level. What is the S-TOPIK? Is it the same as the "traditional" [TOPIK test](http://www.topik.go.kr/usr/cmm/subLocation.do?menuSeq=221010201)? In that case, how is the score at the TOPIK test related to the points for the F-2 system?

Comment: As explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_Proficiency_in_Korean), S-TOPIK was the 'standard' test (as opposed to business B-TOPIK) prior to 2014. The difference between S- and B- were removed in 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time of this answer (05/01/2020), the language points are computed using the maximum between

1. the TOPIK level
2. the KIIP language level

Source: phone call to the Immigration helpline 1345.